# asp.net how to access ajax call data in the controller action

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-mvc

as you can see in the example bellow i pass data: to controller action using 
data attribute , how i can access these data in the action ,
i used request['data'], but it didn't worked

```
<script>
    $('#btnSelected').on('click', function (e) {
            var selectedIDs = [];
            $("#myTable tr.selected").each(function (index, row) {
                selectedIDs.push($(row).find("td:first").html());

            });
             var selecteddata =selectedIDs 
             var link = '@Url.Action("ConvertApplication", "Applications")';
            $.ajax({
                url: link,
                type: 'POST',
                data: selecteddata ,
                contentType: 'application/html',
                success: function (content) {
                    $('#ConvertToProject').html(content);
                    },
                error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
                        alert(xhr.status);
                        alert(thrownError);
                    }
                });

        });
    </script>
```

Comment: The data will map to your ActionResult if it is the correct type, read up a bit on the DefaultModelBinder in asp.net

Comment: And why using `contentType: 'application/html'` while passing an array? You must enable `traditional: true` option to pass array with AJAX call.

Answer (score 0):

Your Action should have a List as an input Parameter.

```
Public ActionResult ConvertApplication(List<int> selecteddata)
{
...
}
```

Comment: maybe because it's an ajax call the result could be JsonResult ?